# React native FlatList last gallery item disappers after Youtube full screen

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist, youtubeplayer

I have image/youtube video gallery in FlatList component.
My code is sipmle:

```
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
import YoutubePlayer from 'react-native-youtube-iframe';


const productImages = [
{
  "value_id": 3839714,
  "medium_image": "https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg",
  "media_type": "external-video",
  "video_url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqctAnNZMgI"
},    
{
  "value_id": 1884,
  "medium_image": "https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg",
  "media_type": "image",
  "video_url": null
},
{
  "value_id": 1885,
  "medium_image": "https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg",
  "media_type": "image",
  "video_url": null
},
{
  "value_id": 3839711,
  "medium_image": "https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg",
  "media_type": "external-video",
  "video_url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqctAnNZMgI"
}];

  const renderItem = ({ item, index }:any) => {
      
    if (item.media_type == "external-video") {

      const videoId = item.video_url?.replace("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", "");

      return (
          <View key={index}>
            <YoutubePlayer
                height={270}
                width={400}
                videoId={videoId}
                webViewStyle={{marginTop: 30, marginRight: 15}}
            />
          </View>
      )
    } 

    return (
      <View key={index}>
        <Image resizeMode="contain" resizeMethod='resize' style={{margin: 5, width: 400, height: 300}} source={{ uri: item.medium_image }} />
      </View>
    )
  };
```

main component return:

```
  return <View>
    <FlatList
      data={productImages}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={item => item.value_id.toString()}
      horizontal
      snapToInterval={400}
      decelerationRate="fast"
    />
  </View>
```

Gallery shows ok, but when you:

1. Scroll to the last video
2. Rotate screen to landscape (horizontal) orientation
3. Click  Full screen [] button on youtube player
4. Exit from Full screen mode.

Last video disappers from the gallery, there is just empty space.

[image]

It works ok if keep phone in portrait mode only.

Tried to set up multiple options for controls but no one works.

Appreciate any help!